# How do I get Celery to execute in production on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, celery

I'm using Celery on my Django app.

I can't get the celery task to execute unless I run `celery -A appname worker -l info --pool=solo` in the terminal.

How do I get it execute when the site is in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [`worker` process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model#mapping-the-unix-process-model-to-web-apps) to your `Procfile`, e.g.

```
web: gunicorn some_app.wsgi
worker: celery -A appname worker -l info --pool solo
```

After redeploying, [scale up](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#manual-scaling) one or more workers, e.g. by running

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```